# index === arr.length - 1 returns false every time

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have a function `resFormat(restrictions)` which takes an array of restrictions as a parameter and returns a string which contains diet restrictions. When calling it with `["res1","res2","res3"]`, it should return "res1, res2, res3"

```js
function resFormat(restrictions){
    let result="",i
    for (i in restrictions){
        if(i===restrictions.length-1){ //always returns false 
            result += restrictions[i]
            continue
        }          
        result += restrictions[i]+", "
    }
    return result
}

console.log(resFormat(["res1", "res2", "res3"]));
```

Here `i===restrictions.length-1` should return true when the loop reaches the last element of the array, but it always returns false.

Expected output:

```
res1, res2, res3
```

Actual output:

```
res1, res2, res3,
```

Comment: `i` is a string, `restrictions.length-1` is a number, so `===` will not consider them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you use `for..in` over arrays: it leads to these kinds of errors. `i` will be a string data type, not numerical, since it iterates *properties*.

It would work if you did a loose comparison with `==` instead of `===`, but it still is better to avoid `for..in` when iterating arrays.

Instead you can solve this problem with the native method `join`:

```
restrictions.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when === is changed to ==

```
restrictions = ["res1","res2","res3"]
 let result="",i
        for (i in restrictions){
            if(i==restrictions.length-1){  
                result += restrictions[i]
            } 
            else
                result += restrictions[i]+", "
        }
```

=== is strict equality comparison operator in JavaScript, which returns false for the values which are not of a similar type.

i in this context refers to string and restrictions.length refers to number, you could try by checking with typeof command in javascript and examine the difference.

=== will work only when both operators are of same type.
Hence, under such circumstances I advise you to use == , here content is just checked over here, not the type of operand and suits well in this domain.

Or if you wish to use ===, then value of i must be number, not a string